# Alternative for java applet

Tags: javascript, java, applet

I'm downloading multiple pdf files based on user selection from server via applet making a socket connection. Since applets are no longer supported in Chrome, i'm trying to find other ways to do this functionality.

Is there a way to do it with simple JS ajax call as i want this process to be asynchronous? Please suggest other ways of doing this in the client side, if any.

Tried force download with 
'

```
"content-disposition": attachment;filename=""
```

this doesn't let me trigger "save as" dialog in the browser(as applet enables to do).

With ajax, JS could only receive the response as text and not as pdf. Don't know how to proceed with the response in JS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not content-disposition alone. Try these combination of headers:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=your.pdf
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```